# How to parse the value to decimal?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, decimal

Code:

```
decimal pgr = decimal.Parse("$ 499.00");
```

I am getting the error message as

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

How to parse a value to decimal?

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal d = decimal.Parse("$499.00", NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the string first,

```
decimal pgr = decimal.Parse("$ 499.00".Replace("$", "").Replace(" ", ""));
```

`.Replace(" ", "")` was added in the code to remove all spaces either trailing, leading or in between.